# SwiftSpinner.swift not showing after UIAlert

Tags: swift

I am using a third party indicator called SwiftSpinner.swift. It works great however I am having an issue with trying to show the spinner after a UIAlertAction is shown.

I basically call

```
let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Are you sure you would like to save?", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

let saveYesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

   // SHOW PROGRESS INDICATOR
   SwiftSpinner.show("Saving")
}
```

But the indicator does not show. I am using the same .show code elsewhere in the app and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the sub view to the view already?

```
self.view.addSubview(SwiftSpinner)
```

Also, is SwiftSpinner an instance of the SwiftSpinner object or are you referring to the Class itself with those calls?

The way I usually handle this type of thing is by adding and removing the view as a subview.

Comment: I don't normally need to add it as a subview. I will try that though.

Comment: And referring to the class. Documentation states there is nothing else to do other than use SwiftSpinner.show

Comment: Well, if the spinner is being added to the alert view on that call, then when the alert is dismissed it will disappear. See if calling addSubview in that line helps, Make sure you are on the main thread too - or it could be lingering in the background.

Comment: OK this seems to work but now the issue is that if there is a navigation bar or tab bar SwiftSpinner is under these.

Comment: Hmm. I am not quite sure how to handle that. The reason is that the view is technically embedded in a tab / nav bar. So adding anything to the view by definition puts it under the bar... Maybe consider editing the spinner class to appearing more as a small centered spinner rather than stretching to the edges?

Comment: Yeah. It seems to be adjusting scroll view insets on the new view as well.

Comment: You could also add a view in your storyboard at the very top level. Add the spinner as a subview of that view, and then just hide or show the top level view?

Comment: The problem with that is the view is a tableviewcontroller

Comment: I have posted another question on here. Thanks for getting me this far

Answer (score 0):

Did you import SwiftSpinner ? You need to import SwiftSpinner then technically it should work. If it does not still work, please share your code. maybe your show and hide placement is wrong.